# Python Matplotlib: How to scale the color of scatterplot/errorbar markers with a 3rd variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question seems to have been asked a few times already, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

I am making a `plt.errorbar` plot from the arrays of points `results['logF'], results['R']` which are in a pandas DataFrame. I want to scale the colour of the points with a third variable `results['M']`. I've tried various things but I always get some kind of error, I'm clearly doing something wrong but I can't find any place that explains exactly what is required.

So firstly, `results['M']` are a bunch of floats in the range 0 - 13. So as I understand it, I need to normalise them, which I did with `matplotlib.colors.Normalise(vmin=0.0, vmax=13.0)`.

When I try plotting with the following code:

```
results = get_param_results(totP)
colormap = mlb.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.0, vmax=13.0)
mass_color = np.array(colormap(results['M']))
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
plt.errorbar(results['logF'], results['R'], marker='x', 
         mew=1.2, ms=3.5, capsize=2, c=mass_color,      
         yerr=[results['logF_l'], results['logF_u']], 
         xerr=[results['R_l'], results['R_u']],
         elinewidth=1.2)
```

I get an error `ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional`. Not sure why it should be two dimensional. In other stackoverflow threads, they pass one dimensional arrays and it's fine.

Using a different form (basically just copying the style from another stackoverflow thread), I write:

```
results = get_param_results(totP)
colormap = mlb.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.0, vmax=13.0)
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
plt.errorbar(results['logF'], results['R'], marker='x', 
         mew=1.2, ms=3.5, capsize=2, c=results['M'], cmap=mlb.cm.jet, norm=colormap
         yerr=[results['logF_l'], results['logF_u']], 
         xerr=[results['R_l'], results['R_u']],
         elinewidth=1.2)
```

I get a different error, `TypeError: There is no Line2D property "cmap"`
I don't understand this either (it also doesn't recognise norm), scatter should definitely have the norm and cmap arguments.

Basically, I can't find any great explanations or tutorials on how to get the color scale with an errorbar plot. Can someone help?
Thanks.

EDIT:

Been asked to post the data I'm using. This is the `.head()` table of the `results` DataFrame (the full one has 257 rows).

```
          R       R_l       R_u             F            F_l            F_u  \
0  1.486045  0.068775  0.068508  2.999561e+06  488301.994185  496244.025108
1  0.992957  0.062303  0.062664  4.583829e+04    6652.971755    6636.980813
2  1.422328  0.029163  0.029323  2.068257e+06  186692.732530  187685.738474
3  1.326820  0.094840  0.093995  1.049490e+06  185012.117516  184290.913875
4  0.887831  0.013825  0.013939  5.883107e+05   52537.237452   52492.326206

          M       M_l       M_u      logF    logF_l    logF_u
0  1.030471  0.122698  0.123368  6.471041  0.071150  0.072506
1  2.753916  0.157837  0.160584  4.656550  0.063427  0.063404
2  2.344767  0.340987  0.345171  6.313780  0.039261  0.039548
3  0.918979  0.069931  0.069984  6.014049  0.077296  0.077189
4  1.310289  0.076565  0.076805  5.767830  0.038848  0.038895
```

So basically:

```
results['M'] = array([ 1.03047146,  2.75391626,  2.34476658,  0.91897949,  1.31028926])
results['logF'] = array([ 6.47104102,  4.65655021,  6.31377955,  6.01404944,  5.76782953])
results['R'] = array([ 1.48604489,  0.99295713,  1.42232837,  1.3268205 ,  0.88783067])
```

and etc... (for the error bars, just use an array([1,1,1,1,1]) to save time or something).

I reran the code, by replacing results with the above, and it still gives me `ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional`

I'm not sure what the second dimension should be. Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong when I'm calling the `errorbar` plot function?

Comment: Adding data to your code might improve the chance that someone can help debugging

Comment: Thanks, I just added the .head() of my data in the edit.